# PowerShell regex to pick out elapsed time

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting

I am new to powershell scripting and am not so good with Regex...
I want to create a regular expression that will pick out time from the following text file...

gfskf dakdshadk daksdkdahkd daksdhasdkh () zadf sflh f.d   / sd lhlfhlj f 12hrs:10mins:05sec fsfsf fsfjhsfjh

I want to get the hours so 12 and mins as 10 and seconds as 5.

```
$hour= [regex]::match($line,$hour_regex).Groups[1].Value
$mins= [regex]::match($line,$mins_regex).Groups[1].Value
$sec= [regex]::match($line,$sec_regex).Groups[1].Value
```

So essentially I need three regular expressions to extract the relevant data from the file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one regex:

```
$r = '(\d+)hrs:(\d+)mins:(\d+)sec'
$i = 'hlfhlj f 12hrs:10mins:05sec fsfsf f'
$result = [regex]::match($i,$r)
$hour = $result.Groups[1].Value
$mins = $result.Groups[2].Value
$sec = $result.Groups[3].Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
$a = "gfskf dakdshadk daksdkdahkd daksdhasdkh () zadf sflh f.d / sd lhlfhlj f 12hrs:10mins:05sec fsfsf fsfjhsfjh"

$hour,$min, $sec = $a -split '(\d\d)' | ? { $_ -match '\d\d' }
```

Comment: +1 for originality, but I wouldn't want to rely on this, since the rest of the text may or may not contain more 2+ digit numbers.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good point! I've taked the example line 'literally' ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody mentioned it yet, you can also use the `-match` operator. The submatches can be accessed via the `$matches` hashtable:

```
Get-Content "C:\path\to\your.txt" | ? {
  $_ -match '(\d+)hrs:(\d+)mins:(\d+)sec'
} | % {
  $h = $matches[1]
  $m = $matches[2]
  $s = $matches[3]

  "{0}:{1}:{2}" -f ($h, $m, $s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex capture groups. `"(\d+)hrs:(\d+)mins:(\d+)sec"` will capture the numbers into groups that can be accessed. Save the results in a `MatchCollection` to check the results. Like so,

```
$line = "sflh f.d / sd lhlfhlj f 12hrs:10mins:05sec fsfsf"
PS C:\> $mc = [regex]::match($line, "(\d+)hrs:(\d+)mins:(\d+)sec")
PS C:\> $mc.Groups[1].value
12
PS C:\> $mc.Groups[2].value
10
PS C:\> $mc.Groups[3].value
05
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$b= [regex]".* (\d*)hrs:(\d*)mins:(\d*)sec.*"
$hours=$b.Match($a).groups[1].value
$minutes=$b.Match($a).groups[2].value
$seconds=$b.Match($a).groups[3].value
```

Answer (score 0):

if like me you are not at ease with regex you can use split function :

```
PS>$t="gfskf dakdshadk daksdkdahkd daksdhasdkh () zadf sflh f.d / sd lhlfhlj f 12hrs:10mins:05sec fsfsf fsfjhsfjh"

PS>$slices=$t.split(@(" ",":"))
$hours=($slices[12]).substring(0,2)
$mins=($slices[13]).substring(0,2)
$secs=($slices[14]).substring(0,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PS> $s -replace '^.+ (\d+hrs:\d+mins:\d+sec).*$','$1' -split '\D+' | where {$_}
12
10
05
```